# Testing equality of DataColumn values in C#

Tags: c#, equality, datacolumn

I've written some code to test equality between column values in DataTables when the column type isn't known.

Testing directly like this:

```
row["Foo"] == row["Bar"]
```

always results in false, presumably because object's implementation of Equals uses ReferenceEquals.

So I've resorted to:

```
row["Foo"].ToString() == row["Bar"].ToString()
```

This works (at least for the cases I've encountered so far), but it seems a little, well, manky.

Can anyone think of a reason I shouldn't do it this way, or suggest a better way? Remember I don't know the column types at design time, so casting is not an option.

Thanks

David

Comment: So you're looking for a way to reliably compare equality of two objects that could be of different types?

Comment: Can you explain a little more, why don't you know the types at coding time?

Comment: Justin - sorry I didn't explain. They will be of the same type, but the type is unknown at design time.

Comment: Nazgul - this code is part of a generic function to simulate joins in c#. The equality test is basically the ON clause, but the join could be between strings, guids, ints etc. The function doesn't know in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `row["Foo"].Equals(row["bar"])`.

When you compare objects using == and there is no predefined or user-defined == operator, C# will compare them using reference equality.  If you want to call the Equals method, you need to write it out as a method call.

Answer (score 1):

`row["Foo"].Equals(row["Bar"])` ?

Comment: You're comparing if both object have the same reference, right?

Comment: This is the same (correct) answer as Quartermeister's. I marked his as correct because I couldn't tell which was first and it was higher up the page. Sorry!

Comment: @David actually i was first, but nevermind :) i am not too determined amount extra 15 points

Answer (score 1):

why not use Equals if they are string.

```
row["foo"].ToString().Equals(row["Bar"].ToString());
```